# Appropriate HTTP return for a Rest Service called during blackout times

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

We are building a REST service with WebApi 2.0.  Our business rules dictate that one of our services is only available during certain hours of the day.  What would the appropriate response (HTTP result code and content) to return when someone calls it during off-hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

503 Service Unavailable might be the appropriate response

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html

Comment: Hi Johnathan.  I will accept your answer because the link to w3 answered it for us.  After some internal discussion, we decided that 403 Forbidden seemed to make more sense, because during the blackout times, we are not down for maintenance or due to overload, but because you are procedurally not allowed to access the site during those times (we don't want to convey that the site is malfunctioning or unable to withstand load, but rather that the door is intentionally locked at this time).